# Prevent dropdown to close when clicked on menu items

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap 4 alpha6. Below is my dropdown html:

```
<div class="dropdown">
   <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
   Dropdown
   </button>
   <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
      <h6 class="dropdown-header">
         <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" placeholder="Search">
      </h6>
      <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Action</button>
      <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Another action</button>
      <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Something else here</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

What I want is that not to close the dropdown when someone clicks on any items inside the `.dropdown-menu`. I wrote the below JS but it doesn't working, means still on click on menu items bootstrap dropdown is getting closed.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
      $('.dropdown-menu button').on('click', function (event) {
        console.log(event)
        event.preventDefault();
      })
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried `event.stopPropagation`? https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/ or `event.stopImmediatePropagation`?

Comment: I tried `stopPropagation` but not the other one. Let me try that too.

Comment: @cale_b still same problem. The thing is I don't see the console.log output also..

Answer (score 0):

In your script file you are looking for a p-tag inside the dropdown-menu class but you don´t have any p-tags. Try writing:
```

```
  $('.dropdown-item').on('click', function (event) {
        console.log(event)
        event.preventDefault();
      })
```

```

Comment: that was my typo, I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the following event instead of **click**:

> [hide.bs.dropdown](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/dropdowns/#events): This event is fired immediately when the hide instance method has been called.

When you click on a button a data attribute can be set to the dropdown to save the state. At the beginning you can set this value to false. And finallly, when the dropdown is hiding you may test this value and reset the state.

This event must be attached to your **dropdown** element:

```
$('.dropdown-menu button').on('click', function(e) {
    $('.dropdown').data('canBeClosed', true);
})
$('.dropdown').data('canBeClosed', false);
$('.dropdown').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function (evt) {
    console.log('Event fired: ' + evt.type);
    if ($('.dropdown').data('canBeClosed') == false) {
        evt.preventDefault();
    } else {
        $('.dropdown').data('canBeClosed', false);
    }
})
```

```js
$('.dropdown-menu button').on('click', function(e) {
    $('.dropdown').data('canBeClosed', true);
})
$('.dropdown').data('canBeClosed', false);
$('.dropdown').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function (evt) {
    if ($('.dropdown').data('canBeClosed') == false) {
        evt.preventDefault();
    } else {
      $('.dropdown').data('canBeClosed', false);
    }
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Dropdown
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
        <h6 class="dropdown-header">
            <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" placeholder="Search">
        </h6>
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Action</button>
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Another action</button>
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Something else here</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes, but you can't  close it when u click on the button `.dropdown-toggle`. This is not what I want.

Comment: When u click outside of `.dropdown` or when click the `.dropdown-toggle` button.

Comment: thanks. I tried what you have shown here before I post in SO and it didn't work. So after that I had no idea and came here. :) Take your time, no problem.

Comment: @hobby-coder Answer and snippet updated. I hope it works like you expect